# WKID for Unknown Vertical Projection

Tags: gis, arcobjects

I am creating an ArcGIS 2d featureclass with the projection WKID = 3308. The HasZ option is false. 
To get the Spatial Reference for WKID I am using the IGeometryServer interface:

`int iWKID = Convert.ToInt32(sWKID);
 IGeometryServer pGeomServer = (IGeometryServer)new GeometryServer();
 pSpatRef = pGeomServer.FindSRByWKID("E???", iWKID, 0, true, true);`

I don't want to specify a vertical projection because the featureclass will always be 2D. I tried using 'null' for the WKID_Z and zero (as above) but each run came back with the error that the vertical WKID is not found.

In Intellisense it says the vertical projection is optional but I can't set it to null and I can't omit it. It has to have an integer value.

On the ESRI web site it says WKID_Z is a parameter of type long. Nothing about it being optional.

Is there an integer for the 'unknown' vertical projection?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1):

Well, I created the featureclass with a vertical projection WKID of 5711 (a valid Vert Proj) and when I look at it with ArcCatalog it doesn't mention a vertical projection anywhere (as it shouldn't) so it looks like:

1. The vertical projection value is *not* optional.
2. If you set HasZ = false the vertical projection value is ignored.

Bit odd, but it's ESRI...